# How can i automate a spreadsheet which is stored in google drive without downloading it

Tags: python, excel

**How can i automate a spreadsheet which is stored in google drive without downloading it.**
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I want to read and write some column of my spreadsheet. but I dont have permission to download it.

Comment: @ pro_cheats - I tried openpyxl module but it is allowing only those sheets who are stored in cwd .

Comment: Then you may not be able to modify it due to security reasons.

Comment: pro_cheats - if somehow i  download it , so is it possible to modify it locally and override the local file to the original one.

Comment: try it out, you might be able to modify it locally, but may not be able to write it back to the original one.

Comment: @GauravKothyari Are you talking about downloading the samples file from that terrible link?  You do have permission for that file, but when looking for programming tutorials, try to avoid the sites whose main objective is to sell you stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Read permission on a folder (called `View` permission on Google Drive), you can open and run code from a workbook stored there, however technically the file is still being downloaded to your local machine, likely in a temporary folder.

If you have Write permission on a folder (called `Edit` permission on Google Drive), you can replace/overwrite a file that's stored there.

> **View**: People can view, but can’t change or share the file with others.
>
> **Comment**: People can make comments and suggestions, but can’t change or share the file with others.
>
> **Edit**: People can make changes, accept or reject suggestions, and share the file with others.

---

### More Information :

- Google Support : [**Share files from Google Drive**](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822)
- Microsoft.com : [**Windows Temporary Files**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/92635/windows-temporary-files)